# Mocha stopped logging describe and it strings just dots

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, mocha.js

I updated nodejs (io.js `v2.5.0`) and I stopped getting mocha verbose logging. How can I get it back?

```
thomas@workstation:untitled$ mocha test/fse-symlink-path.js 
(node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
(node) smalloc is deprecated. Use typed arrays instead.

  ․․․․․․․․․․․․

  12 passing (24ms)
```

Comment: which version of mocha?

Comment: Have you tried
DEBUG=* mocha test/fse-symlink-path.js

Comment: @bluesman Thats not what I want, I just want to restore normal functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed a newer version of io.js using nvm it seems it moved me to using an older version of mocha.